# How to catch runtime exception on mapview.setRegion function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mkmapview

I have an outlet (MKMapView) named `alertMap` and in my `viewWillAppear` I set up the initial view of my `alertMap`.

```
func centerMapOnLocation(_ location: CLLocation) -> Bool {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 1.0, regionRadius * 1.0)

    alertMap.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)    // TODO: crash

    return true
}
```

Sometimes in my code (and I don't know why, but this is another question for another time...) my location coordinates are bad stored in my API, causing crash on the function above.

I tried several methods to "catch" the exception but it seems impossible.

How can I catch this runtime error.

The error read:

```
2017-02-28 12:54:33.400319 myApp[10433:2647466] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+1197269.18497000, -7972692.46846000 span:+0.00895306, -0.62941112>'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1869091b8 0x18534055c 0x186908e80 0x192bffa0c 0x1000bd77c 0x1000bc728 0x1000bd4c0 0x18c7d6754 0x18c7d64cc 0x18cb0cf04 0x18ca4ffdc 0x18ca41d50 0x18c7b10b4 0x1868b60c0 0x1868b3cf0 0x1868b4180 0x1867e22b8 0x188296198 0x18c8297fc 0x18c824534 0x100130530 0x1857c55b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: "but this is another question for another time..." I disagree. You are trying to solve something by ignoring the problem and work around it. Let's say you spend an hour on this and manage to work around your problem. Is your code fixed? No. The problem still exists except now you've spent (wasted) time on it with no result. Fix the problem. It looks like the coordinate you are passing in is not valid. Where is it coming from?

Comment: @Fogmeister you are totally right. I am working in that issue too. But time is tight so I have to release the app with the error handling.

Comment: please add the code to your question that you have to create the location.

Comment: My stack includes iOS and Android apps. For iOS I am using `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` `let currentLocation = locationManager.location`  and `longitude = currentLocation!.coordinate.longitude` (same with latitude)

Comment: is it not possible to copy and paste the code? Your coordinate is (1197269, -7972692) that is not a valid coordinate in any system. Whatever is creating that is doing something wrong, without seeing any code it is impossible to help.

Comment: location manager would not create a location with those coordinates. Like the error says, it's an invalid coordinate. Can you copy and paste the function into the question. Just edit the question. Why do people on this site so adamantly refuse help?!?!

Comment: @Fogmeister sorry for that, but my code is split in several locations. I tried to copy here: http://pastebin.com/mF9xByph it starts with sendLocalNotificationForBeaconRegion after a iBeacon is detected by monitoring operations,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by a couple of different people:

1. You shouldn't be trying to ignore runtime exceptions in the first place.  Even in Objective-C this should be considered a last resort.
2. Even if you wanted to ignore runtime exceptions, swift won't allow you to.

What you need to be doing is verifying the data with guard blocks, and then tracing back to root cause your problem, something like:

```
func centerMapOnLocation(_ location: CLLocation) -> Bool {
    guard (-90.0 ... 90.0).contains(location.coordinate.latitude) else {
        print("Unexpected latitude value \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
        return false
    }

    guard (-180.0 ... 180.0).contains(location.coordinate.longitude) else {
        print("Unexpected longitude value \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        return false
    }

    guard (0 ..< 10000.0).contains(regionRadius) else {
        print("Unexpected region radius \(regionRadius)")
        return false
    }

    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 1.0, regionRadius * 1.0)

    alertMap.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)    // TODO: crash

    return true
}
```

Comment: Definitely. Although, I'd be checking further up the stack where that location is created. Those coordinates are way off. Almost look like memory addresses rather than ints.

Comment: Yeah, really just trying to present an approach more than a solution :)

Comment: @DavidBerry great validation. I didn't have the idea how to validate this type of data. For now it works and it answers my question

Comment: @po5i ok, now you have validation but all this will do is stop the map centering. If you could just copy and paste the code that creates the location then we can see WHY it is creating the invalid location in the first place.

Comment: Or put a breakpoint on the print lines and look up the stack and see where the data becomes bad?

Comment: Yes, the data is already bad and stored in the backend. I'm still trying to find who is the responsible. Probably is the python backend itself because when I had it deployed in another server none of this happened.